# Design for reloading configuration dependency of java class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, configuration

Suppose this is a configuration data object that I read from DB/XML:

```
class ConfigurationClass{

     //some configurations
     public String getString(){

     }
}
```

Now this is the class that uses this configuration object

```
class ConfigurationUser implements Reloadable{

     private ConfigurationClass configuration;

     //some extra logic required for making object ready to use
     public void init(){
         // some new object is created based on configuration
         SomeObject obj = new SomeObject(configuration.getString());

         //register to configuration manager 
     }

     @Override
     public void reload(){
        //does whole reloading stuff
        //creates a new instance of configuration class and reads new configuration which is not appropriate
     }
}
```

Now when I have to reload the configuration then suppose I create a new instance of `ConfigurationClass` and inject it in `ConfigurationUser` class.
But I will also have to re-initialize the object, so that it can create new configuration dependent objects.

Is this a proper design to do it or there is a better approach? I thought of using Spring or Google Juice for DI, but again I will have to provide the **callback** to the configuration user class, that configuration has been reloaded.

I am new to using IoC containers so dont know if it is possible. **Need to use this in real time server application so have to be strict about garbage production and performance.**

Current solution:

```
public interface Reloadable{

    public void reload(); 
}
```

I have a configuration manager to which I register all the configuration user instances, and when reload is to be done, manager just calls `reload` and it reads new configuration and re initializes all dependent objects.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for an [Observer/Listener design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Your configuration user should be an "observer" and a configuration itself will be a "subject". First, the observer registers itself in a subject. Next, every time a subject is changed it notifies all observers, and they reload (or do anything they wish).

Comment: yes my current solution is somewhat similar to this. Is ther any other way of doing it?

Comment: I have a base class which uses JAXB to read configuration from XML. So on reload is this the responsibility of base class to give the callback?

Comment: Exactly. Those who stays closer to the actual changes of data is responsible for notifying others about them